# Loop in javascript over integers

Tags: javascript, loops, integer

I am still newbie in javascript

I am looking for a simple loop in javascript with iteration over integers where I am not interested in the item.

in python it looks like this: `for i in range(10)`

in ruby: `(1..10).each`

the simplest example in javascript I found is this:

```
_.each(Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0)
```

Do you familiar with simpler example?

Comment: [Google "javascript loops"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=javascript+loops).

Comment: _"where I am not interested in the item"_ - What are you interested in? Please describe more clearly what output you expect.

Comment: for someone who can come up with loops in several other languages am amazed couldn't find answer in 3 minutes doing web search

Comment: kind of 'i don't even want to bother searching' post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Underscore and you prefer a functional programming style, which your example suggests, try this:

```
 _.times(5, function(e) { console.log(e) })
```

Comment: If you are using lodash, there is a range function which can be used

Answer (score 13):

You could use  a simple for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // i is your integer
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursive function :

```
function loop(n, fn) {
    n && (fn(), loop(--n, fn));
}
```

Usage :

```
loop(3, function () {
    alert('One more time!')
});
```

Comment: This is dangerous and can cause memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

While loop:

```
var i = 10; while (i--) {
    // do something 10 times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this, because a needed to split and get each integer from long integers. I solved doing:

```
let getArrayToLoop = theNumber.toString().split('');

// then you can loop with for, for ... in, map

for(let i = 0; i < getArrayToLoop.length; i++) {
    console.log(getArrayToLoop[i]) // this is a string, you could 
                                   //Number(getArrayToLoop[i]) *if needed
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x="",i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
  x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```